# how to do a job based on time that user has entered

Tags: java, database, spring, scheduled-tasks

I have some entities in a database. Every entity have a field called `time`.
This `time` field has been entered from the user side. I want to call a method on that particular `time`.

(For example imagine a system that will call to your phone in a specific time that you have set before.)

I know that a possible solution is to use a thread that checks the `time` field in the database at every second, but what is the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `Spring-Scheduler` [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html). There you can define your own `Scheduler` instance. This has a method called `schedule()` which can be called with a specific task and a `(Cron)Trigger`. On the time the user saves the entity with the given time you can create a new `(Cron)Trigger` to schedule the task.

```
scheduler.schedule(task, new CronTrigger("0 15 9-17 * * MON-FRI"));
```

Comment: Yes! I was familiar with spring scheduler but not with trigger. That's the solution. Thanks.